# Save the line break in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, newline, jtextfield

How to save the line break when insert text from the Clipboard into the JTextField?

I found way to solve this problem. 
It is `setDocument()` method from `JTextField`:

```java
public void setDocument(Document doc) {
    if (doc != null) {
        doc.putProperty("filterNewlines", Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    super.setDocument(doc);
}
```

Plus to this create your own realization of `AbstractDocument`, which will have single-line structure.

Comment: I don't need to display string with line breaks, I need to when I call `txtField.getText()` I get string with line breaks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [final character '\n' at the end of my string has been modified to space character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372468/final-character-n-at-the-end-of-my-string-has-been-modified-to-space-characte)

Answer (score 3):

A JTextField is for a single line of text only. You can use a JTextArea instead.

Answer (score 3):

`JTextField` doesn't support multiple line text. Use `JTextArea` or `JEditorPane` instead.