# final character '\n' at the end of my string has been modified to space character

Tags: java, swing, newline, jtextfield

I was hoping to retrieve the newline character at the end of the text in a `JTextField`, however after setting the text field's text to my string, it has been modified to be a space character. The code below highlights the problem.

Is it possible to preserve the `\n` in the text field?

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class StackOver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hasNewLineEscapeCharacter = makeStringWithNewLineCharacter();
        JTextField backgroundText = new JTextField(90);
        backgroundText.setText(hasNewLineEscapeCharacter);
        char spaceChar = backgroundText.getText().charAt(backgroundText.getText().length()-1);
        char newLineChar = hasNewLineEscapeCharacter.charAt(needsNewLineEscapeCharacter.length()-1);
    }

    public static String makeStringWithNewLineCharacter() {
        String str = "hello,world!";
        str += ('\n');
        return str;
    }       
}
```

Comment: No, I don't believe it is, but why would you even want to do so? JTextFields are for single line text entering and display. If you need multiple line entry, use the proper tool for the job such as a JTextArea

Comment: There's no such thing as an empty character.

Comment: You're question is in fact an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) question where the issue is you're taking the wrong approach to solving an overall problem, one that you've not told us yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to preserve the '\n' in my JTextField?

A `JTextField` uses a `PlainDocument` which contains a property that filters the "\n" and replaces it with a space character.

To preserve the newline character in the text field you can try:

```
textField.getDocument().putProperty("filterNewlines", Boolean.FALSE);
```

However, this will cause the text to display on two lines just like a text area.

So as suggested above you should just be using a JTextArea.

There is no way to display text that contains a newline character on a single line.

What you might want to do is store some other unprintable character in the text string and then use a String.replaceAll(...) if you ever need to access the text with the newline character added back in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `JTextField` to not only *display*, but also *accept* newlines when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, you also need to add an `ActionListener`. If you subclass `JTextField` (you may use a *factory method* instead), it might look like this:

```
public class JMultilineTextField extends JTextField {
    public JMultilineTextField() {
        addActionListener(e -> {
            try {
                final int selectionStart = getSelectionStart();
                final int selectionEnd = getSelectionEnd();

                final Document document = getDocument();
                if (selectionStart != selectionEnd) {
                    document.remove(selectionStart, selectionEnd - selectionStart);
                }
                document.insertString(selectionStart, "\n", null);
            } catch (final BadLocationException ble) {
                // Unlikely to happen, but add your error handling code here.
                ble.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But this brings another problem: your `JTextField` will grow or shrink vertically as newlines are added or removed, and you need the parent component to reflect the change in the text field size and layout its children accordingly (otherwise, you may well end up having overlapping *Swing* components). This problem can be solved by installing a `DocumentListener` into your text field's `Document`:

```
public class JMultilineTextField extends JTextField {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void setDocument(final Document doc) {
        setupDocument(doc);

        super.setDocument(doc);
    }

    private void setupDocument(final Document doc) {
        doc.putProperty("filterNewlines", false);
        installDocumentListenerIfNecessary(doc);
    }

    private void installDocumentListenerIfNecessary(final Document doc) {
        final DocumentListener documentListeners[] = ((AbstractDocument) doc).getListeners(DocumentListener.class);
        if (Stream.of(documentListeners).noneMatch(documentListener -> documentListener instanceof RowCountChangeListener)) {
            doc.addDocumentListener(new RowCountChangeListener());
        }
    }

    private final class RowCountChangeListener implements DocumentListener {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(final DocumentEvent e) {
            revalidateParentIfNecessary();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(final DocumentEvent e) {
            revalidateParentIfNecessary();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(final DocumentEvent e) {
            revalidateParentIfNecessary();
        }

        private void revalidateParentIfNecessary() {
            final JMultilineTextField textField = JMultilineTextField.this;

            final Dimension currentSize = textField.getSize();
            final Dimension preferredSize = textField.getPreferredSize();

            /*
             * Grow/shrink vertically as necessary.
             */
            if (currentSize.height != preferredSize.height) {
                textField.getParent().revalidate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also suggest that you call `setupDocument()` from your text field's constructor:

```
public class JMultilineTextField extends JTextField {
    public JMultilineTextField() {
        setupDocument(getDocument());

        // add ActionListener, etc.
    }

    // ...
}
```

[Full code](https://gist.github.com/unix-junkie/cac9c3e088ff5ef9ce9166e07c34d969).